# Vim Parrot Os not installing

Tags: linux-kernel, parrot-os

Hello guys I've been trying to install vim on my parrot Os but each and every time I encounter the same error. I've tried upgrading, updating and still i encounter the very same problem here is the error. Somebody give me a solution.

```
V└──╼ #sudo apt-get install vim -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ant-contrib coinor-libcbc3 coinor-libcgl1 coinor-libclp1
  coinor-libcoinmp1v5 coinor-libcoinutils3v5 coinor-libosi1v5
  firebird3.0-server-core firebird3.0-utils fonts-opensymbol
  gcc-8-base:i386 libabw-0.1-1 libapache-poi-java libbase-java
  libbcmail-java libbcpkix-java libboost-iostreams1.62.0
  libboost-locale1.62.0 libcdr-0.1-1 libclucene-contribs1v5
  libclucene-core1v5 libcmis-0.5-5v5 libcommons-collections4-java
  libcurvesapi-java libdee-1.0-4 libe-book-0.1-1 libehcache-java libeot0
  libepubgen-0.1-1 libetonyek-0.1-1 libexttextcat-2.0-0
  libexttextcat-data libflute-java libfonts-java libformula-java
  libfreehand-0.1-1 libgpgmepp6 libhogweed4:i386 libhsqldb1.8.0-java
  libib-util libicu4j-java libintellij-annotations-java libisl19
  libitext-java libjcommon-java libjetbrains-annotations-java
  liblangtag-common liblangtag1 liblayout-java liblinear3 libloader-java
  libmspub-0.1-1 libmwaw-0.3-3 libmythes-1.2-0 libnettle6:i386
  libnumbertext-1.0-0 libnumbertext-data libodfgen-0.1-1 liborcus-0.13-0
  libpagemaker-0.0-0 libpentaho-reporting-flow-engine-java libpixie-java
  libqxp-0.0-0 libraptor2-0 librasqal3 librdf0 libreoffice-style-colibre
  libreoffice-style-tango librepository-java librevenge-0.0-0 libsac-java
  libsaxonhe-java libserializer-java libstaroffice-0.0-0 libvisio-0.1-1
  libwpd-0.10-10 libwpg-0.3-3 libwps-0.4-4 libxml-java libxmlbeans-java
  libxmlsec1-nss libzeitgeist-2.0-0 libzmf-0.0-0 lp-solve zeitgeist-core
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  vim-common vim-runtime
Suggested packages:
  ctags vim-doc vim-scripts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  vim vim-runtime
The following packages will be upgraded:
  vim-common
1 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2973 not upgraded.
Need to get 7,579 kB of archives.
After this operation, 34.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Ign:1 http://deb.parrotsec.org/parrot parrot/main amd64 vim-common all 2:8.1.2269-1
Ign:2 http://deb.parrotsec.org/parrot parrot/main amd64 vim-runtime all 2:8.1.2269-1
Err:3 http://deb.parrotsec.org/parrot parrot/main amd64 vim amd64 2:8.1.2269-1+b2
  404  Not Found [IP: 104.24.124.114 80]
Err:1 http://deb.parrotsec.org/parrot parrot/main amd64 vim-common all 2:8.1.2269-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 104.24.124.114 80]
Err:2 http://deb.parrotsec.org/parrot parrot/main amd64 vim-runtime all 2:8.1.2269-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 104.24.124.114 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.parrotsec.org/parrot/pool/main/v/vim/vim-common_8.1.2269-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 104.24.124.114 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.parrotsec.org/parrot/pool/main/v/vim/vim-runtime_8.1.2269-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 104.24.124.114 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.parrotsec.org/parrot/pool/main/v/vim/vim_8.1.2269-1+b2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 104.24.124.114 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your computer isn't able to connect with the vim repository. I could be fixed by

`sudo apt update && sudo apt-get update`

also, check your sources file to make sure the repositories added are correct.